# Logic and Inequalities

Tags: inequality, logic

Im taking a first year uni maths course and there's a question on our assignment that I'm a little stuck with.

the question asks, if r is a positive real number, **in terms of r what is the largest value of s (also positive and real) that will make the following inequality true**:

$$ \left ( \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \right ) \left | x - 1 \right |< s   \Rightarrow   \left | \frac{1}{x} -1 \right |< r $$

I like to work it out myself so that I actually learn it, but i feel like I need a push in the right direction as I have really got no idea how to approach this sort of problem.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: express |x| in terms of s, also $\left | \frac{1 - x}{x} \right |< r$

Comment: Off the top of my head, you'll definitely need $s\le1,$ regardless of $r.$

Answer (score 2):

The expression: $~\forall x\in \Bbb R ~(\lvert x-1\rvert < s \to \lvert \tfrac 1 x-1\rvert < r)$

Is equivalent to: $~\neg \exists x\in \Bbb R~(s> \lvert x-1\rvert \wedge \lvert \tfrac 1 x-1\rvert\lvert x\rvert \geq r\lvert x\rvert)$

So ...

Answer (score 0):

$|\frac1x||x-1|<|\frac1x|s\implies|1-\frac1x|<|\frac1x|s\implies|\frac1x-1|<|\frac1x|s$
So let $r=\frac s{|x|}$

Comment: But $r$ is *given*....

Comment: @cameronbuie then rearrage for $s$

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a better hint.

Answer (score 0):

Notice

$$|x-1| = |1 - x| = |x(\frac{1}{x} - 1)| = |x||\frac{1}{x} - 1|$$

Consider 
$$|x-1| = |x||\frac{1}{x} - 1|<s$$

Since $|x| > 0$ this implies that

$$|\frac{1}{x} - 1|<\frac{s}{|x|}$$